# C# Save/Load objects to/from files: single instances

Tags: c#, file, memory, load, save

I am working on a windows application tool. The tool lets the user build data.
I am looking for a way to save the user's work into a file. I heard about XML serialisation, but I haven't found an answer to the following question:

Say I have 2 lists, and there are objects that are referenced to from both lists (both lists point to the same instance of the object). If I go over both lists to save all the objects, will that object be saved only once, since it is a single instance, or will it be saved twice, since it is referenced to from both lists?

Also, when loading the file, I want to be able to know that it was a single object and that it was referenced to from both lists (basically load up the exact memory image I had before).

Can XML serialisation do that in C#?
Or if there's a better way, what is it?

Thanks,
M.

Comment: Oops, my original answer was quite wrong, I rewrote it.

Answer (score 1):

The [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) will not retain object references. After you deserialize, [`object.ReferenceEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) will return false, where it would've returned true before serialization.

What you need to use is a [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) and set [`PreserveObjectReferences`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.preserveobjectreferences.aspx), this will solve your case.

Alternatively, if you must use XML, you can add attributes yourself and use the deserialize events to re-instantiate any object references, but this requires quite some work.